# Colonization of the Siberian taiga by engineering crops and ecosystem

Tags: humans, fauna, flora, genetic-engineering

(REVISED)
It usually is common sense to believe that any crops would just die within Siberian soil. But I just thought about creating genetically modified crops which are adapted to boreal, permafrost climates, basically adapted to shallower grounds. Roots are shorter but more numerous, resulting in more numerous but smaller products:
[image]

Another commonly encountered problem is the infamous acidic podsol, which is not-so good for agriculture, I had the idea that just like in the Pleistocene park, a created ecosystem could sustain agriculture there by introducing herbivores which would alter the ecosystem in order to make the landscape a grassland or forest-steppe by grazing.

I am thinking how it would be feasible like how such a process could be done in order to create an entirely new and productive ecosystem. How could we do that?

Comment: "plants which warms the body of humans and animals" – this is what firewood is

Comment: By far the main problem is that Russia does not have anywhere near enough people to populate its immense territory. *If* they had enough people they could begin with the low-lying fruit and start by colonizing the *European part* of Russia. The conditions are a hundred times better than in Siberia, there is a lot of land available (4,000,000 square km, 95% of the area of the European Union), it is very sparsely populated (28 people per square km compared to 106 in the E.U.), a lot of it is arable land (easily more than three times as much arable land as the entire E.U.)...

Answer (score 4):

**Possible? Yes. Feasible...probably not**. First, note that the Taiga regions of Earth *are* colonized, and settlements have been able to sustain themselves for millennia. It appears that you are asking about expanding the colonization to create far larger settlements, though. I can only speak with reasonable confidence about Northern Canada, so I'm not sure if this is universally true, but:

The first issue that must be solved is...bugs. The bug seasons are absolutely insane in the North, to the point that some (non permafrost) regions of Canada are reasonable for agriculture and other settlement are basically not used for that because the bugs are intolerable. You will need a way to figure out how to avoid the influx of bugs in the spring for larger settlements without just killing all of the bugs, since they form an important part of the food chain up there.

The next issue is infrastructure. One of the issues with getting so far up North is the near complete lack of roads leading there. It's easier to fly than to drive to some towns, but that means that if you want a mass migration of people you're either going to need thousands upon thousands of flights (and associated air infrastructure) or lots of road building. That is not a trivial thing, and roads built in regions with considerable seasonal weather is hugely difficult. Interestingly, this would mean that there would be lots of jobs available, but most of them might be road maintenance!

Then you have to deal with agriculture. Up North the growing season is exceptionally short and the winters are very harsh. You would need an agricultural community based around super fast growing, high yield plants. I am not aware of any such plants.

The "obvious" answer here is to use greenhouses, but then you come up against at least two problems: first, the winters are extremely harsh, so you would need some form of greenhouse that is not only insulated but also able to withstand huge freeze/thaw cycles. That would mean you'd need a large space inside and artificial lighting, which brings us to problem 2: energy. Without the infrastructure in place, good sources of high energy density like nuclear would be very, very difficult to build. Plus there's that damn winter problem again! You'd need a maintainable nuclear plant that can sustain a settlement throughout many winters.

Ultimately, I can see a technological way of colonizing the North, but it would be a giant money sink. The question you'd have to answer is: why are you going? If the reasons for the colonization outweigh the immense cost of fixing the challenges, then sure.

Comment: Could be worse, could be trying to colonize Mars…

Comment: @StarfishPrime exactly why we don't have space colonies and won't in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Before our current taiga epoch started, most of Siberia was actually covered by "[mammoth steppes](https://pleistocenepark.ru/)" - arid land covered by cereal-bearing grasses pasture where mammoths, wooly rhinos and their ilk lived. Only later on the megafauna gave way and let the forests and swamps take their place.

Russians (and other inhabitants of these lands such as Yakuts) also grow a variety of crops in Siberia, such as hard wheat and rye. There's no economic neccesity right now, since you can grow crops much cheaper elsewhere, but it is certainly possible if you are ready to pay for it.

Comment: Interesting, I have heard and read about the Mammoth steppes being fertile lands. Although Russia will probably start with the European part, in my story, my country spans Siberia, Tibet, all of Mongol lands and Manchuria. Besides the last one, such land would possibly be more economically challenging. But the ideal in my world would be a population boom in the middle of Siberia and its eastern (and northern) coasts after the people living there would be engineered to bear the cold better than us.

Comment: In the middle of Siberia there is a city of Yakutsk, pop 350k. How much of a boom are we talking about?

Comment: Well the total population of Siberia rises up to 400 million.

Comment: At this point you are probably using some kind of vertical farming / domed cities and not caring about soil agriculture.

Comment: what is the reason soil agriculture is not possible for such a population? Could I lower it? I don't want to put my people in domes to be honest.

Comment: Even the USA which owns a huge chunk of prime land only has 350 million people. Here you want a country owning comparable amount of junk land have more people. This suggests advancing to very unconventional urban tech.

Comment: Well I thought that Siberia had more flat plains (which are bigger than all parts of US which are green on the map and its grasslands too). But I didn't expect agriculture to be so difficult. I actually am looking for a form of engineered agriculture which could then be permanently used. If agriculture like that needs futuristic technology besides genetic editing, then descending to 340 is okay for me.

Comment: The USA is basically a single big plain with Rockies on the side, isn't it. There's fewer greens precisely because there's agriculture. You sholf start by calculating current population of that land.

Comment: I know the US is filled with mountains on every side, I just didn't think of it by now. But speaking of calculating, the combined territories of my country in OTL, Northeast, Western China and Inner Mongolia, Central Asia and North Asia account to a population of 341 000 000 in gross, that's why I thought that with more agriculture in Siberia including the Arctic, this would reach 400 000 000. But Siberia has far more plains than all of the US.

Comment: When you have relatively fertile/temperate Northern China and Central Asia, how are you going to force people move to Siberia, and especially northern coastal areas? You will likely end up with the current population distribution where Siberia is mostly mined for raw materials.

Comment: I agree it is interesting if not crucial to develop the social aspects. But to respond to your question, I have thought of sending few, ideologically very convinced people into Siberia and then convince them of having lots of children as the Siberian agricultural technology grows until reaching the northeastern, cold portions of Siberia. That's my hypothesis.

Comment: It does not work that way. Most of modern largest cities are made of people who did the inverse transition, e.g. born in big families of countryside and moved back to where the opportunities are.

Comment: Perhaps I am a bad sociologist, but what if we give people the opportunity to do agriculture in Siberia and pay them enough to develop technology if my question is plausible?

Comment: Do you see many people around you who are looking for an opportunity to do agriculture anywhere? Agriculture is 2% of economy and it's not obvious how it would pay for cars, medical care, housing and education of arctic farmers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142998/discussion-between-bangerblade-and-alamar).